# как сделать правильный вывод?

Tags: python, функции, list

при выводе чисел последнее число не выводится, как это решить подскажите

```py
def pipe_fix(nums):
    return list(range(nums[0],nums[-1]))
```

мне нужен чтобы функция выводила следующий список: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
а выводит вот такой: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `range` возвращает диапазон, не включая последнее число:

```py
>>> list(range(0, 9))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Для решения этой проблемы надо просто добавить `+ 1`:

```py
def pipe_fix(nums):
    return list(range(nums[0], nums[-1] + 1))
    #                                  ^^^^
```

Comment: спасибо<3 помогло

Comment: @445r, если вам помог ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галочка слева).